# How to show all mails with no restriction of user?

Tags: odoo

I am in need of showing "All Mails" that have been transacted in OpenERP 7 with no restrictions.

There seems to be some restrictions done when records are fetched from Database(postgresql).

Is there a way to show all the records available in postgresql directly?

Answer (score 0):

Their are several ways, you can use any of below:

- You can create Separate menu without any domain on mail.message object which will show you all the messages.
- Also you can create the postgres view report for more statistical information on  mail.message object this will be tricky and long but informative in future.
- Or Even you can remove the Domain from the existing Email menu action to show all the  record without any restriction.

Thank You

Comment: but some records are hidden or not available in `Settings--> Email--> Messages` itself.  I tried to remove the user restriction but had less count of records than in the postgresql(backend)

Comment: @atchuthan: So it that case you can create new menu on the object and get access to all record without any restriction.

Comment: yeah, i tried it, but the records were still restricted before the records are fetched from backend
Is there any way to override the restrictions done before getting records from postgresql